# Selecting a specific id in a table with multiple entries of the same name

Tags: php, sql

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to choose a row from a table that has multiple rows of the same name, but different version IDs.
I'm working with a large table(~12k rows) that has information like id, name, version_id. There are several rows that have the same 'name' for each entry, and they all contain a different version_id, up to 24. However, some entries only go to 21. I attempted to just call the version ids to 21, but the most recent 130 entries only have version_id 23 and 24.
I didn't make this table and it would be extremely tedious and long to go through and change the version IDs of every row that I need, so I've come to ask if there's a simple way to check if a row has a version_id 24, and if not, to use version_id 21 instead(as all entries have one or the other. Some go from 1-21, some from 1-24, and some are 23-24. there are no exceptions)

If there is absolutely no way to do this through SQL, I'm just going to run a loop through every entry to check version Ids, which I feel will hit performance hard.

Here is what the table looks like that I'm trying to choose the version id from. Some records go to only 21, and some start at 23. 
[image]

also, here is my current sql:

```
SELECT pokemon.id, pokemon_species_flavor_text.flavor_text, pokemon_species_names.genus,     pokemon_species_names.name, GROUP_CONCAT(type_names.name)
FROM pokemon, pokemon_species_flavor_text, pokemon_species_names, type_names, pokemon_types
WHERE pokemon.species_id = pokemon_species_flavor_text.species_id
AND pokemon.species_id = pokemon_species_names.pokemon_species_id
AND pokemon_types.pokemon_id = pokemon.id
AND pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id
AND pokemon_species_flavor_text.version_id =21
AND pokemon.id <2000
AND pokemon_species_names.local_language_id =9
AND type_names.local_language_id =9
GROUP BY pokemon.id, pokemon_species_names.name
```

I'm not sure if I could use a WHERE NOT EXISTS in there since I'm trying to pull so many different things at once.

Comment: Are you able to post the table structure please? And perhaps examples of 5-6 records so I know exactly what I'm working with and I can hopefully put something together for you. :)

My understanding is you want every row that has a version_id that's not 24 to instead have a version_id of 21?

Comment: yes first of all provide us the structure of your table. On the other side I think what you need is SQL-JOIN

Comment: You could make a subquery that does GROUP BY name and gets the MAX(version), then JOIN the original table to that and use the MAX(version) to choose the row you want. I can't really give you an example unless you post the table structure but that oughta work.

Comment: I added the structure of the pokemon_species_flavor_text table and also added my current SQL. It currently just selects all rows with version_id 21, and some records don't have that. also, sorry it took so long to reply.

Answer (score 0):

A typical SQL method to get the last version is to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.version > t.version
                 );
```

What this says is:  "Get me all the rows from the table where there is no row with the same name and a higher version number".  A convoluted (but accurate enough) way of saying:  "Get me the row with the highest version number".

This will make good use of an index on `table(name, version)` for most databases.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do this because of how much stuff I'm trying to pull at once. Or how I would even do it if it is possible. I'm trying to pull several records at once, and I dunno if that's possible using where not exists.

Comment: @KruSuPhy . . . This answer was motivated by the statement "Here is what the table looks like that I'm trying to choose the version id from."  If you really meant "query result" rather than table, then you need to repeat the joins and logic in the subquery.